# Okta Redirect url for proxy adding client ID

Tags: reactjs, oauth, oauth-2.0, access-token, okta

I have an internal application which is using [Implicit flow](https://developer.okta.com/docs/concepts/auth-overview/#implicit-flow) for Authentication. However, since this is a Single Page Application in React JS (using `@okta/okta-react` and `@okta/okta-signin-widget`), there is no way to store client id securely within React Code. So, I have added an AWS Lambda (accessed through API gateway) as a decorator to which the call will be forwarded from React application, this Lambda will then decorate the call with Okta login url, attaching the client ID, before forwarding the call to Okta for Access token.

App.js code snippets:

```
<Security
      issuer="https://dev-123456.okta.com/oauth2/default"
      client_id="012some345client6789id"
      redirect_uri={window.location.origin + '/implicit/callback'}
      onAuthRequired={onAuthRequired}
    >
```

and

```
<Route
            path="/login"
            render={() => (
              <Login baseUrl="https://dev-123456.okta.com" />
            )}
          />
```

with modules `okta-react` and `okta-signin-widget`, call to Okta authentication is made, how can I change this call to go through the decorator, and decorator forwarding the call to actual Okta urls.

Refer: [Sample Code repo](https://github.com/nitin1706/react_otka_auth) and [app.js code](https://github.com/nitin1706/react_otka_auth/blob/master/src/App.js)

Comment: It's OK to include the clientId in your code. You can think of the number as a license plate on a car. It's just an identifier. The clientSecret is the value you don't want to store in your app, or in source control.

Comment: @Matt But if I am not wrong, for implicit flow, I just need the client _id, `/authorize` endpoint should get me access_token identifying request based on client_id. Where does client_secret comes in for implicit flow?

Comment: There is no client_secret in the implicit flow. You can also use authorization code flow (with PKCE) with all of Okta's client SDKs now. We recommend using this over implicit flow https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/05/01/is-the-oauth-implicit-flow-dead.

Comment: @MattRaible: Agree, but this is an internal app. So, for this case, client_id is only key of matter, what are the options to hide that. Coming back to original question, How can request be routed to decorator and from there to Okta.

Comment: You don't need to hide the clientId. You seem to be doing a lot of work for something that's OK to expose to end-users.